SignatureDoesNotMatch Errors When Using Pre-Signed URLs with MinIO in Docker and Node JS
I am running MinIO inside a Docker Compose setup and using the minio-js SDK to generate pre-signed URLs for accessing files. However, when I attempt to access these URLs, I encounter  SignatureDoesNotMatch errors, depending on whether I use minio or localhost in the URL. I've tried multiple approaches, including configuring a custom network in Docker, but the issue persists. I need help understanding why these errors occur and how to resolve them.
I'm working on a project using MinIO to store and serve files. I'm running MinIO inside a Docker container and trying to generate pre-signed URLs for objects stored in a MinIO bucket. The URLs are being generated successfully, but when I try to access the objects using these URLs, I encounter issues.
Details:

MinIO Setup:

MinIO is running inside a Docker container on my local machine.
The MinIO service is exposed on the port 9000 and the console on the port 9001.
I've configured the MinIO client (mc) to connect to the MinIO server and list and upload objects without issues.


Docker Compose Configuration:

My Docker Compose file defines several services: minio, a Node.js app (projectk), MongoDB, and Redis.

The Node.js app uses the minio service as its MINIO_ENDPOINT and attempts to generate pre-signed URLs for accessing objects stored in MinIO.

I have tried multiple approaches to resolve the issue, such as setting up a custom network and specifying a static IP address for the MinIO container. These approaches are commented out in the configuration below.
version: '3.4'

services:
  minio:
      image: minio/minio
      command: server /data --console-address ':9001'
      volumes:
        - minio_data:/data
      ports:
        - "9000:9000" 
        - "9001:9001"
      environment:
        MINIO_ROOT_USER: "minioadmin"
        MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "minioadmin"
      # MINIO_DOMAIN: "localhost"
      # MINIO_SERVER_URL: http://localhost:9000
      # MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://localhost:9000
      # MINIO_SERVER_URL: http://localhost:9001
      # CONSOLE_SECURE_TLS_REDIRECT: "off"
      # networks:
      #   my_network:
      #     ipv4_address: 172.22.0.2

  projectk:
    image: projectk
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: "yarn dev"
    volumes: 
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      FORCE_COLOR: 1
      MINIO_ENDPOINT: "minio"
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - minio
      - mongo
      - redis
    # networks:
    #   my_network:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    # networks:
    #   my_network:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    # networks:
    #   my_network:

# networks:
#   my_network:
#     driver: bridge
#     ipam:
#       config:
#         - subnet: 172.22.0.0/24

volumes:
  mongodata:
  minio_data:





URL Generation:

I'm using the presignedUrl method from the minio-js SDK to generate pre-signed URLs for objects in my MinIO buckets.
const Minio = require("minio");

// Create a MinIO client
const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
  endPoint: process.env.MINIO_ENDPOINT,
  port: 9000, 
  useSSL: false, 
  accessKey: process.env.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.MINIO_SECRET_KEY,
});

const generateMinioPresignedUrl = async (bucketName, objectName, expiry = 60 * 60) => {
  try {
    const presignedUrl = await minioClient.presignedGetObject(bucketName, objectName, expiry);
    return presignedUrl;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error generating pre-signed URL:", err);
    return "failed to obtain accessUrl";
  }
};


The URLs generated look like this:
http://minio:9000/users-documents/filename.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256...




Problems Encountered:

When I try to access the pre-signed URL, I can't access it because the minio:9000 endpoint is only accessible inside the Docker container.

http://minio:9000/users-documents/filename.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256...


If I replace minio with localhost in the URL, I get a different error:
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <Key>filename.jpg</Key>
  <BucketName>users-documents</BucketName>
  <Resource>/users-documents/filename.jpg</Resource>
  <RequestId>17F0DBA572E215F0</RequestId>
  <HostId>dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8</HostId>
</Error>





Environment Configuration:

Docker Compose Setup:

The MINIO_ENDPOINT in my Node.js application is set to minio. if I use localhost it throws connection error.
The MinIO client in my code is configured with the correct access and secret keys, and can successfully connect to MinIO.


MinIO Client (mc) Configuration:

The MinIO client is configured with the correct endpoint and credentials, and I can successfully list and upload objects to my buckets using mc.



What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the buckets and objects exist and have the correct permissions.
Configured the bucket policy to allow public access using mc.
Checked the MinIO server logs for any relevant error messages.
Attempted to generate and access pre-signed URLs using different configurations (localhost (gives connection error) vs minio).

Questions:

Why am I getting AccessDenied or SignatureDoesNotMatch  errors when trying to access objects using pre-signed URLs?
Is there a specific way I should be configuring the MinIO client or the URL generation to avoid these issues?
How should I handle the hostname in the generated URL (minio vs localhost) when accessing MinIO within a Docker container


setup endPoint: in minIO client to localhost or use a proxy pass with host header in ngnix reverse proxy
